# Need assistance regarding autolayouts

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autolayout, constraints

I have a `UIView` of size 196x269 yellow color and inside I have another `UIView` green color and using `auto layout` it is positioned like this

[image]

but I am getting this error

[image]

But if I set the layout of the yellow view, every thing is fine no errors.

[image]

My question is that green view is inside and its layouts are also set, why it is dependent of yellow view position/layouts?

Comment: Adding to Bladebunny, it looks like, if you want a reusable view, you should make your green and yellow view a separate xib (subview), which you can then load into other xibs. (Realtime preview takes some extra code using xibs though). However, as Blade says, you will still need to define the containing frame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Auto layout is based on linear algebra.  The relevance being that it has to be able to 'solve' the 'equation' based on the constraints you provide.  It looks like you are trying to set the constraints for the inner view while leaving the outer view undefined.  That won't work because the 'solution' for the inner view layout is dependent on the outer.  Which is why it then works when you do specify the outer layout constraints.  The system then has enough information to find a 'solution'.